# Ansible vault doesn't save changes with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, ansible, ansible-vault

I'm running ansible 1.9.4 on OSX installed via pip.

If I do `ansible-vault create x`, then make some changes and save, then the file appears blank whenever I do `ansible-vault view x` or `ansible-vault edit x`.

I've got Sublime Text 3 as my $EDITOR. When I set it to vim instead, it all works as expected, and I can edit and save my files encrypted with ansible-vault. Any idea what could be happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think it'll work with the standard Sublime command line launcher. `ansible-vault` waits for the editor process to exit before encrypting the temp file it creates- the Sublime launcher exits immediately, so you end up with an empty vault file.

EDIT:

To make it work with the standard Sublime command line launcher, you have to specify the -w flag, which will stop the `subl` process from existing until the file is closed in sublime text. (see [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html))

So your `.bashrc` should have a line like this:

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

Comment: Turns out to make it work you just have to use export EDITOR='subl -w' (the -w flag won't exit the subl process until the file is closed in sublime). I'll add that to your answer.

Comment: Excellent find- I'll be using that myself... Thanks!